# Is something like "or" acceptable in conditional tests defined by \newif?

Tags: conditionals

I am using conditional tests in my `.cls` file which has two options "`final`" and "`draft`".
I am rather familiar with conditional tests but I am just curious to know how to define the "`or`" in the following code.

```
\if@‎final OR ‎\if@draft FINAL TEST ‎‎ ‎\else NO TEST‎ ‎\fi\fi
```

### Edit:

I have tried the following code and have gotten the desired result, so I just want to know whether I CAN use something like "`\or`" in `\newif` conditional or not. In other word, does such a command (I mean `\or`) exist at all?

```
‎\documentclass[‎draft‎]‎{article}‎
‎\makeatletter‎
‎‎\newif\if@‎final‎
‎\@‎final‎false‎
‎\DeclareOption{‎final‎}{\@‎final‎true}‎
‎\newif\if@‎draft‎‎
‎\@‎draft‎false‎
‎\DeclareOption{‎draft‎}{\@‎draft‎true}‎‎
‎‎\ProcessOptions‎‎‎
‎\newcommand{‎\mytest‎}‎{\if@‎final FINAL TEST ‎\else‎  ‎\if@draft FINAL TEST ‎‎ ‎\else ‎NO ‎TEST‎ ‎\fi\fi‎‎‎‎‎}‎‎
‎‎\makeatother‎
‎\begin{document}‎
‎\mytest‎
‎‎\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have different outputs based on whether you're `final` or `draft`, since your faux `if` statement doesn't show it?

Comment: In both cases, I want to have "FINAL TEST" on my output.

Comment: Yes, `\or` exists, but is not used in the context of boolean expressions like you might be used to. Instead it is used as a choice conditioning when using `\ifcase`. See some [examples of `\or`](http://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html#or-rp) in the TeX Primitive Control Sequence Reference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The basis for your `OR` statement looks like this:

```
\if@final TRUE\else\if@draft TRUE\else FALSE\fi\fi
```

The following minimal example illustrates this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@final \newif\if@draft
\newcommand{\test}{\if@final TRUE\else\if@draft TRUE\else FALSE\fi\fi}
% final = false; draft = false
\@finalfalse \@draftfalse \test

% final = true; draft = false
\@finaltrue \@draftfalse \test

% final = false; draft = true
\@finalfalse \@drafttrue \test

% final = true; draft = true
\@finaltrue \@drafttrue \test
\end{document}
```

yielding the `OR` truth table:

[image]

Comparable output is obtained by using booleans defined via [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
%\newif\if@final \newif\if@draft
\newbool{@final} \newbool{@draft}
\newcommand{\test}{\ifboolexpr{bool {@final} or bool {@draft}}{TRUE}{FALSE}}
% final = false; draft = false
\boolfalse{@final} \boolfalse{@draft} \test

% final = true; draft = false
\booltrue{@final} \boolfalse{@draft} \test

% final = false; draft = true
\boolfalse{@final} \booltrue{@draft} \test

% final = true; draft = true
\booltrue{@final} \booltrue{@draft} \test
\end{document}
```

Of course, you can change the `TRUE`/`FALSE` output to whatever you want.

---

As Marco remarked, `etoolbox`'s boolean flags provide a front-end to LaTeX's `\newif`. As such you can either define them using `\newbool` or `\newif`. See section **3.5 Boolean Flags** (p 12 onward) of the [`etoolbox` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf).

Comment: **Since \ifboolexpr and \ifboolexpe imply processing overhead, there is generally no benefit in employing them for a single/simple test.** etoolbox documentation.